# Defrag during/"after" shutdown?

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, defragment

I use [PageDefrag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageDefrag) to keep my page-file healthy, and have it set to run at every boot with a 1sec timeout. I think it would be really handy to be able to defrag the rest of my machine every-time I tell my machine to shut-down (not restart). If it could activate after windows has killed all the background processes and provide a little information on it's progress it would be very useful.

Is there anything that can do this, or is there a way I can "hook" a batch file/command into the shut-down process to run "defrag.exe"?

**Please Note:** I'm not looking for something that can defrag *then* shutdown, but rather initiate the shutdown procedure (to close all running/background apps) and then *pause* the shutdown to run the defrag while there are no locked files.

Comment: For whatever solution you find: ensure it doesn't interfere with Windows Update, which sometimes runs during shutdown as well?

Answer (score 1):

I use [O&O Defrag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O&O_Defrag) and it can do the equivalent: it can shutdown the computer after having run the boot-time defragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Batch-File which is running f.e. [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) and shuts down the machine afterwards, like this:

```
C:\PathToMyDefrag\MyDefrag.exe -r "yourSxriptHere"
shutdown -s -f -t 00
```

The MyDefrag-Script does need the following line it:

```
WhenFinished(exit)
```